# Using not uploaded file in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

Is it possible to use not uploaded files for example images in your jupyter notebook or is there a script for uploading files into your jupyter notebook? I have done some research but didn't find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For sure! Like an usual python script. Let's say you want to open a file named "file.txt" and read its content.

```
with open("the/path/of/file.txt", "r") as file:
    text = file.read()
```

Now an image using cv2 named picture.jpg

```
image = cv2.imread("the/path/of/the/image/picture.png)
```